# Tv show name and name of episode

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

This is not *Black Mirror*. This show was way before *Black Mirror*.

People were liked, disliked, or ranked in some voting system.  If they got to many negative responses from population they were sentenced to death. I believe one character was first arrested for making a negative comment about a statue or famous person of that population/dimension.

Comment: Please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info. There's a list of prompts there to help elicit more details, which you can edit into your question.

Comment: And you tagged time-travel. Is that present in the show, or were you aiming for "tv"?

Comment: It was really different dimensions.

Comment: And the protagonists routinely changed dimensions?

Comment: Each episode they were in a different dimension/universe. The plot in this particular episode had the cast seeing the culture of this universe able to vote on liking, disliking, or rating someone's behaviour or look. If enougj negative was voted then they could be put to death.

Comment: I believe one character made a bad remark about a hero of that dimension or a statue of them. One character was wearing a hat I believe to cover up something that could identify them as not being human.

Comment: *Sliders* would be my first bet, but I can't find a matching episode.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sliders_episodes

Comment: Sliders is what I thought too but I don't think it was around when like and dislike was around in social media.

Comment: I know the OP calls for a show older than 'Black Mirror' but I feel like  I should mention Seth McFarlane's new show 'The Orville" because this is exactly the storyline to the s1 e7 Majority Rule... I am sure the storyline is not new and has happened before, but maybe you are remembering an episode that was actually new? -
 Though there are no dimensions... http://orville.wikia.com/wiki/Majority_Rule

Comment: *Otherworld* is a possibility. Not actually alternate worlds, but the "zones" worked similarly. Not familiar with the episodes, though.

Comment: Thanks but not Orville.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it. I've read the excerpt but I don't know what tv show it is or the what the name of the episode is called.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at it on YouTube and yes it is The Orville and Majority Rules!

Answer (score 9):

Not way before Black Mirror, but could it have been "[Majority Rule](http://orville.wikia.com/wiki/Majority_Rule)" of *The Orville*? Seems to hit all of the details.

> In a police station, LaMarr sits before Publicity Officer Willks, who explains that LaMarr's slew of downvotes come because his **suggestive dancing on a statue of a Sargun hero** was recorded by others and uploaded to the Master Feed, an online video and voting platform. LaMarr had surpassed one million **downvotes**, which made what he did a "crime against the State." LaMarr was arrested and must go on an apology tour, several live television appearances that will be judged by the public for his sincerity by voting in the Master Feed. If he accumulates over 10 million downvotes by the end of his tour, he will be forcefully corrected via a neurological readjustment called Social Correction.

Comment: I would've commented like @odin1806 but I don't have enough rep yet

Comment: You really *shouldn't* have commented to suggest an answer. That's what *answers* are for.